# Monitor unix process with Nagios Core

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, nagios, apache2, nrpe

I'm begginer with Nagios and i'm trying to monitor if a specific process on my unix machine is up or not.
Server and client are on the same machine : Trying to monitor that machine from a Nagios runing on it.
I've installed Nagios Core 4, nrpe and it's plugins. After looking on the web, I found an answer of how to monitor process using check_procs plugin (up or down) and that's what I actually have in my files :

1- in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg

```
server_address=127.0.0.1
command[check_service]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C $ARG1$
```

2- I created a file called "ubunutu_host.cfg" in /usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/ :

```
# Ubuntu Host configuration file
    define host {
            use                          linux-server
            host_name                    ubuntu_host
            alias                        Ubuntu Host
            address                      127.0.0.1
            register                     1
    }


    define service {
          host_name                       ubuntu_host
          service_description             check_apache2
          check_command                   check_service!apache2
          max_check_attempts              2
          check_interval                  2
          retry_interval                  2
          check_period                    24x7
          check_freshness                 1
          contact_groups                  admins
          notification_interval           2
          notification_period             24x7
          notifications_enabled           1
          register                        1
    }
```

3- In /etc/nagios-plugins/configp/rocs.cfg :

```
define command{
command_name check_service
command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C ‘$ARG1$’
}
```

My probelm is :
when runing this command :

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C apache2
```

that's what I'm having as a result

```
PROCS OK: 7 processes with command name 'apache2' | procs=7;;1:;0;
```

BUT In Nagios, below what I'm having (apache2 is always critical) :
[Problem proc apache2 is always shown critical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Snh9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've already resolved this but I can see the problem is because you have dodgy quotation marks around $ARG1$ in your command definition

You've got `‘$ARG1$’` but it should be `'$ARG1$'` (or even `$ARG1$` if the argument will never have spaces!).